# What is this image next to the YouTube logo referencing?

Tags: youtube

I see the following logo next to my YouTube logo on my home screen. [Reverse image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiv1Oc1fr3PzWEpBEQobwq01THBhWd_1nr2wYsUCNnh1B-dcJaZRIzlcjQemtEHUqE41uicru3ulLEZCr-q_1shTSSJbKgU8uy2qHF-zjuygLv0ttBB4Qrl0YLxdCqMto8OsZDqNUDLTP9J3aL7jzMebFRGvtQp0APC8CeeOucngKkPNg_1xjQmGS2vgcZ-3s2N5-EWFWHj-h4SdBYlUTFrrgVOUETo-KDMjTU06Z6s_1pQha8WbereHOyzOPbvNbzNHLxxAjKgbG8w9-HaTepf8Lupe7okFe4qwzAatkxZK-ZdrwSA6zM6xk4uF4OTNcVLT_1uWM9i63tiwpMtUCETXvbxE1xvCx5g) suggests a connection to American Sign Language but since I see only two results I'm not sure, and YouTube doesn't seem to have made any release I can find? If it's referencing a new ASL feature, does anyone know how to use said feature? (Googling anything about this is hard because adding "YouTube" to any search gives me a bunch of videos and no useful information.)

Does anyone know what it's about?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I should be subscribed to YouTube on YouTube. I see it's related to [celebrating Black history](https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube) which is what the official YouTube channel is featuring!

Edit: Now that I know what to search for, I see that the logo is being updated periodically and [this blog](https://9to5google.com/2021/02/14/youtube-bhm-logo/) seems to be tracking changes!

Comment: That was my first thought. You should accept your own answer

Comment: I can do so only in 2 days!

Comment: Okay I learned 2  new things today!